# Get Firebase data to Algolia search indexing

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, algolia

I am trying to get a large dataset in Firebase database to Algolia for search indexing and every time I get a timeout error, what does that mean and how can I solve it?

I have created a node.js application to copy the data over and is as below. I can copy small data, say 10 contacts just fine, the problem is 3,000 contacts.

```js
const algoliasearch = require('algoliasearch');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');  
const firebase = require('firebase');

// load values from the .env file in this directory into process.env
dotenv.load();

// configure firebase
firebase.initializeApp({
  databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
});
const database = firebase.database();

// configure algolia
const algolia = algoliasearch(
  process.env.ALGOLIA_APP_ID,
  process.env.ALGOLIA_API_KEY
);
const index = algolia.initIndex(process.env.ALGOLIA_INDEX_NAME);


// Get all contacts from Firebase
database.ref('/contactDetail/brazil').once('value', contacts => {
  // Build an array of all records to push to Algolia
  const records = [];
  contacts.forEach(contact => {
    // get the key and data from the snapshot
    const childKey = contact.key;
    const childData = contact.val();
    // We set the Algolia objectID as the Firebase .key
    childData.objectID = childKey;
    // Add object for indexing
    records.push(childData);
  });

  // Add or update new objects
  index
    .saveObjects(records)
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Contacts imported into Algolia');
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error when importing contact into Algolia', error);
      process.exit(1);
    });
});
```

I get a snippet of the contacts json and the following message:

```
   contentLength: 854068,
   method: 'POST',
   timeouts: [Object],
   url: '/1/indexes/app_NAME/batch',
   startTime: 2018-01-17T20:35:27.239Z,
   endTime: 2018-01-17T20:35:39.242Z,
   duration: 12003 } ] }
```

Comment: What is getting kicked back from your console.error?

Comment: console does not report any error. Dont know why

Comment: did you try a generic console.log?

Comment: I tried the generic one and does report `database.ref('/contactDetail/brazil').once('value', contacts => {
  // Build an array of all records to push to Algolia
  console.log("Logged in to firebase");
  const records = [];`

Comment: Hi @ndheti 3000 might be too big as a single save for Algolia, what you could try is to save chunks of objects, there's a good gist that is showing how to do that here: https://gist.github.com/romelgomez/c98991b90fb3b57981b5

Comment: i ended up uploading the data directly to algolia and firebase functions can still update algolia on  changes